# zsh script that lists emualtor, runs it, then installs react native app

Tags: android, react-native, shell, zsh, emulation

I am trying to start an Android emulator command line that works fine, but it never goes to the npx react-native run-android line from the script after it is loaded.  Is there something I need to do?

```
    emulator -list-avds

    # Ask the user if they want to run the app on the simulator
    read -p "Which Android emulator name (i.e. Pixel_7_Pro_API_34)?: " device

    emulator -avd $device

    npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the `emulator` binary you're calling, but I would guess it creates a sub-shell, and you want to pass the npx command into *that* shell

Comment: @mike-flynn does it work the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to launch the selected emulator in background, wait for it to start and then execute the npx command. The final script will be like the following:

```
emulator -list-avds

# Ask the user if they want to run the app on the simulator
read -p "Which Android emulator name (i.e. Pixel_7_Pro_API_34)?:" device

emulator -avd $device &

adb wait-for-device

npx react-native run-android
```

hope this helps